# Angularjs Datatables Custom Expandable Rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

So I am creating a angular datatable by this format:  https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome  I have a button at the end of specific rows(information for that not needed), and if the user clicks on the button, the row expands showing more information about the row that was clicked.  I see examples of people using jquery, but is it possible to do it with angularjs.  Any help, tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Just add the extra columns and use the [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) attribute to show/hide them. If you want examples you should post your code.

Comment: Yes, why not post the code. The question is unanswerable without it.